# GRUB rescue after deleting linux partition in windows dual boot

Tags: linux, grub

Using HP probook 6470b 
I was using linux in dual boot and Bios is in legacy mod.
Now i delete partition  where linux installed and and then when i restart my laptop  my laptop stuck at HP logo and then i open boot menu and select boot from hard drive and then grub rescue comes up( night mare  ) i tried many method available on internet watch videos on youtube but most of solution was these commands in grub mode

ls
Set boot=(hd0,msdos5)
Set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
After i type 
Insmod normal

This gives me error
Unknown file system 
And exit command also not working

---

Then i decided to install new window and create a bootable usb flash and then i select usb in boot menu grub comss here to....

Comment: Boot with Windows bootable media and run `bcdboot C:\Windows`.

Comment: How i can run that in bootable media ?

Comment: Create a USB stick Windows installation drive from a running windows computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more a Windows question than anything else.

Comment: @Kiwy I've discussed this subject at length [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5290/should-we-have-a-stock-answer-for-broken-windows-boot).  The short version is that I don't believe we should simply bump such questions without doing something to assist.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I think they should be move to SuperUser which as a way more capable Windows community. But that's only a matter of opinion. I'm glad you offer an answer .

Comment: @Kiwy ultimately the OP may end up there and should be directed there.  The challenge with a simple question migration ensuring the OP is equipped with enough (Linux) knowledge of what just happened to their system so they know what to ask for.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common mistake. The reason you've hit this is that grub relies on having some configuration files stored on a file system that it can access.  When grub is installed in legacy mode (to the MBR) that instillation includes a reference to the partition containing the config files.

It's most common that these grub configuration files are stored on your Linux partition and NOT a partition reserved only for grub's use.  When you trashed your Linux partition you also wiped out grub's configuration.

To get back to a working system you have two options:

## 1) Reinstall the Windows boot-loader

This will remove grub altogether.

@Biswapriyo as suggested that you boot with Windows bootable media and run:

```
bcdboot C:\Windows. – Biswapriyo
```

As unix.stackexchange.com is not a Windows QA site, I'd forward further questions on how to do this to superuser.com

## 2) Fix grub

If you want to keep grub then you could re-install Linux OR you could use a Linux live CD to manually fix the problem.  Installing Linux seems the larger option, but it does everything for you.

When you do, make sure that you create a small partition mounted to `/boot/grub`.  You can use the command `update-grub` to populate `/boot/grub` and `grub-install` will re-configure grub to use your new partition.

After that you can destroy your Linux partition (if you re-installed linux) as long as you don't remove your grub config partition.